# TortoiseSVN GUI from python

Tags: python, tortoisesvn

I need to launch tortoiseSVN GUI (for example Check For Modifications window) from python. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke Tortoise from command line, on Python you can try doing something like this:

```
import os
os.system('"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:your_command your_args /path:your_path')
```

Where you will replace command and path like you need. 
The path for TortoiseProc.exe can be read from registry, if you are running on windows is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseSVN and then read the ProcPath value.

I can not test this right now, but i think this is what you want to know.

Comment: Thanks so much for your full answer, Yes, it is what I wanted to know! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please, read this: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html

Check for modifications will be look like:

```
tortoiseproc /command:repostatus /path:c:\path\to\working\copy
```